# Laravel output single row from database

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-blade

I am a beginner at Laravel, and I am stuck :)

I am building a simple CMS for a costumer with a rather simple website.
I have created a database for all the text throughout the site, which I want to be able to edit. All the CRUD is working, but I can't seem to output the content from the database, with blade, to the actual view, as I get the error that the variable doesnt exist.

I thought I would be doing something like this {{ $text->"insert specific id" }}
My table has strings for id's to identify the respective text-content thoughout the site.

I have a MainController and a TextController, which is the one dealing with the CRUD of the text-elements.

I am probably forgetting a simple thing, but I just can't seem to work it out.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Text;
use Session;

class TextController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $texts = Text::all();

    return view('texts.index')->withTexts($texts);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, array(

        'content' => 'required'
        ));

    $text = new Text;
    $text->content = $request->content;
    $text->save();


    return redirect()->route('texts.index');
}


/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $text = Text::find($id);
    return view('texts.edit')->withText($text);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $text = Text::find($id);
    $this->validate($request, array(

        'content' => 'required'
        ));

    $text->content = $request->content;
    $text->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Teksten blev ændret!');

    return redirect()->route('texts.index');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

I would think that I am missing something in the MainController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Session;
use App\Text;


class MainController extends Controller
{
public function index(){

    return view('index');
}
```

Could that be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These videos should help: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/5 and https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
    $texts = Text::all();

    return view('texts.index', compact('texts'));
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach ($texts as $text)
     {!! $text->content !!}
@endforeach
```

also compact() accept an array. You can do something like this `compact(['first', 'second', 'third'])`

Comment: Thank you! I see what I did wrong before :) but now I am not sure how to output a specific ID from that text database?

Comment: Same way:

`public function edit($id)
{
    $text = Text::findOrFail($id);

    return view('texts.edit', compact('text'));
}`

then in your view:

`$text->id
$text->content`

Comment: But that doesnt give me a specific id. The table has a string for en id: "forside_tekst" and then the content: "Example", and I need to output the content, how do I specify that the "forside_tekst" is the id that I want

Comment: Can you explain with more details what exactly want to do.

Comment: I have a table with a string as id and then the content.
These rows represent the bits of text around the website I want to be able to edit
I have made the CRUD so that this is possible. But now, I need to output the content of a specific id to the place in the view, where it is supposed to be shown. For instance, the first id is called front-headline and the content is: Welcome to my page.
How do I get this to be the content of the <h1>{{ "the content from the database" }}</h1> on the index page?

Comment: In your routes.php:

`Route::get('/{name}', 'TextController@show')`

In your controller

`public function show($name)
{
        $text =  Text::where('string_id', $name)->first();
    
       return view('example.example', compact('text'));
}`

then in your view:

`<h1>$text->content</h1>`

Something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `with()` flashes content to a session, rather you need to pass in the variables to the view

```
view('index', $data)
```

Where `$data` is the data from the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do I need to change anything in the TextController or would I be able to do this in the MainController alone?

Comment: You should really consider reading the docs, it's amazing how simple things like this are explained over there. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views.

Comment: You are right! I tried reading a lot of search results from the doc, but my problem was that I never found the right one :) But thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In controller you have to select data you want to pass to view

```
$texts = Text::get(); //or Text::all(); for all results
$text = Text::find($id); //if you want one item get by ID
$text = Text::where('column', 'value')->first(); //first item matching condition
```

//and then pass it to view as second parameter (array) in view function)

```
return view('index', ['texts' => $texts, 'text' => $text] /* or compact('texts', 'text') */);
```

//then in view

```
@foreach($texts as $t)
{{$t->content}}
@endforeach

or
{{$text->content}}
```